# How to check what the base location of a Web Service is at Start-up

Tags: vb.net, wcf

Morning folks,

I have a Web API written in vb.net and in the `Application_Start` I'd like to be able to see where the service is running (eg: http://localhost:57851).  Is this possible?

Comment: Hey, do you use basicHTTP Binding ? 
If so pls try HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()

Comment: @Twiebie That's not available in Application_OnStart.

Comment: When launched from VS in localhost, what does `HostingEnvironment.SiteName` give you? My answer below should work in production.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work for localhost apps launched from VS, but does work in production when the app is hosted by IIS.

```
Friend Shared HostName As String = String.Empty
Friend Shared IPAddress As String = String.Empty

...

Shared Sub GetHostInfo()
    ' Get the sites section from the AppPool.config 
    Dim Section As Administration.ConfigurationSection = Administration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(Nothing, Nothing, "system.applicationHost/sites")

    For Each Site As Administration.ConfigurationElement In Section.GetCollection
        ' Find the right Site in the collection...
        If Site("name").ToString.Equals(HostingEnvironment.SiteName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            ' For each binding see if they are http based and return the port and protocol 
            For Each Binding As Administration.ConfigurationElement In Site.GetCollection("bindings")
                If Binding("protocol").ToString.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                    ' IP is first of 3 colon-delimited parts, so just split on colon
                    ' Example: 11.22.33.44:80:www.example.com (IP:Port:Host)
                    With Split(Binding("bindingInformation").ToString, ":")
                        IPAddress = .GetValue(0).ToString
                        HostName = .GetValue(2).ToString

                        ' We found our site and got our bindings, so we can bail out
                        Exit Sub
                    End With
                End If
            Next

            ' We found our site but if we got this far, no HTTP(S) binding was found
            ' This should not happen in production...might happen in localhost testing
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    ' We never found our site...this should not happen in production...might happen in localhost testing
End Sub
```